# Form preview Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, preview

I'm trying to use django's FormPreview but can't get it to work properly. Here's my code:

models.py

```
class jobpost(models.Model):
    CONTENT_CHANNELS = (
        ('Full Time','Full Time'),
        ('Part Time','Part Time'),
        ('Contract','Contract'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    job_id =             models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable = False)
    job_type =        models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, choices=CONTENT_CHANNELS,default='Full Time')
    job_location =    models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    job_title =             models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    job_description =       models.TextField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        #return self.user
        return self.job_location
        return self.job_type
        return self.job_title
        return self.job_description

admin.site.register(jobpost)


class jobpostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = jobpost
        fields = ('user','job_type','job_location','job_title','job_description')

    widgets = {
        'job_type':RadioSelect(),    
        'job_location':TextInput(attrs={'size':'70'}),   
        'job_description':Textarea(attrs={'cols':200, 'rows':10}),

    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'horizontal-form'
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-jobpostform'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
             #self.helper.form_action = '/'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit_addcontent', 'Submit'))
        super(jobpostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def main_page(request):
    """
    If users are authenticated, direct them to the main page. Otherwise, take
    them to the login page.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = jobpostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()

                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
            form = jobpostForm()

    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))


   return render_to_response('portal/job_post.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

preview.py

```
class SomeModelFormPreview(FormPreview):
    form_template = 'portal/job_post.html'
    preview_template = 'portal/preview.html'


    def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
        f = self.form(request.POST)
        f.save()

        pdb.set_trace()
        print "done"
        # Do something with the cleaned_data, then redirect
        # to a "success" page.
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/form/success')
```

job_post.html

```
<form action = "" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="blueForms" id="id-jobpostform">

{% csrf_token %}

{% crispy form %}


<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Post" >
```

urls.py

(r'^$', main_page),
(r'^post/$', SomeModelFormPreview(jobpostForm)),

When i submit the form it goes to the / home page and submits the info. I want to first prview the form and then submit..plz tell me what i am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: http://pydoc.net/Python/django-cbv-formpreview/0.1.0a1/cbv_formpreview.preview/

Comment: You should really follow PEP-8 when coding your application, your fellow programmers will inevitably thank you for that.

Comment: If i want to give the edit form option..how can i pass the entered form values to edit form?